What type of composition is (count 1 2 3,)
I understand (count 1 2 3,) is a composition, because I see its type is 105.
q)type(count 5 6,)
105h

Initially I thought this is an example of implicit composition, which

Compose one or more unary values with a higher-rank value

I thought the values are

unary: count
unary: 1 2 3
binary: , (join)

However, I don't think that's correct because , (join operator) has rank 2, but the result of the composition only has rank 1. This goes against what I read, i.e. result of composition should have the same rank as the last value.
Could someone help explain how exactly this composition works?
I suspect the "composed values" are instead

unary: count
unary: 1 2 3,

If this is the case, doesn't composing a series of unary values require an @ (apply at) as stated at the bottom of this page?

It is implicit composition but is created in a different order giving a different outcome.
The example from the site:

0|+ is noun rank2 rank2

This example binds the noun to the rank2 to it's right leaving the trailing rank2 giving the rank of the whole composition as 2.
Your example:

count 5 6, is rank1 noun rank2

This example again binds the noun to rank2 to it's right which drops it to rank 1 before composing

https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#prefix-infix-postfix
https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syntax/#nouns

